# Spliting string to array by number

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have two functions to split string to array of strings. 
Input string is: (1Letter E|V|R) + 8 number, last component of string (1Letter + V) + 8 or less numbers.

I'v got two functions advised to use, both of them are working properly. But I can't decide which one is better to use.

1st:

```
- (NSArray *) componentSaparetedByLength:(NSUInteger) length{
        NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray new];
        NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, length);
        NSString *subString = nil;
        while (range.location + range.length <= self.length) {
            subString = [self substringWithRange:range];
            [array addObject:subString];
            //Edit
            range.location = range.length + range.location;
            //Edit
            range.length = length;
        }

        if(range.location<self.length){
            subString = [self substringFromIndex:range.location];
            [array addObject:subString];
        }
        return array;
}
```

2nd:

```
NSMutableArray *brokenString=[NSMutableArray new];

int start=0;
for (; start<mainString.length-9; start+=9) {
     [brokenString addObject:[mainString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(start, 9)]];
}
[brokenString addObject:[mainString substringFromIndex:start]];
NSLog(@"->%@",brokenString);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would favor the first category approach, as it takes benefit of a great Objective-C feature: extend existing classes with new methods.

On the other hand probably both ways will fail if it comes to more advanced characters, like [surrogate pairs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#Code_points_U.2B10000_to_U.2B10FFFF), base characters plus [combining marks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character), [Hangul jamo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hangul), and [Indic consonant clusters](http://rishida.net/scripts/indic-overview/#consonantclusters).

So here is my Category implementation:

```
@interface NSString (Split)
-(NSArray *)arrayBySplittingWithMaximumSize:(NSUInteger)size;
@end

@implementation NSString (Split)

-(NSArray *)arrayBySplittingWithMaximumSize:(NSUInteger)size
{
    NSMutableArray *letterArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    [self enumerateSubstringsInRange:NSMakeRange(0, [self length])
                                options:(NSStringEnumerationByComposedCharacterSequences)
                             usingBlock:^(NSString *substring,
                                          NSRange substringRange,
                                          NSRange enclosingRange,
                                          BOOL *stop) {
                                 [letterArray addObject:substring];
                             }];


    NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
    [letterArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        if (idx%size == 0) {
            [array addObject: [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:size]];
        }
        NSMutableString *string = [array objectAtIndex:[array count]-1];
        [string appendString:obj];

    }];

    return array;
}
```

use it like:

```
NSArray *arraysWith9Letters = [letters arraysBySplittingWithMaximumSize:9];
```

This approach could be easily extended to split by words, sentences, lines too

```
@interface NSString (Split)
-(NSArray *)arrayBySplittingWithMaximumSize:(NSUInteger)size
                                     options:(NSStringEnumerationOptions) option;
@end

@implementation NSString (Split)

-(NSArray *)arrayBySplittingWithMaximumSize:(NSUInteger)size
                                     options:(NSStringEnumerationOptions) option
{
    NSMutableArray *letterArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    [self enumerateSubstringsInRange:NSMakeRange(0, [self length])
                                options:(option)
                             usingBlock:^(NSString *substring,
                                          NSRange substringRange,
                                          NSRange enclosingRange,
                                          BOOL *stop) {
                                 [letterArray addObject:substring];
                             }];


    NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
    [letterArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        if (idx%size == 0) {
            [array addObject: [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:size]];
        }
        NSMutableString *string = [array objectAtIndex:[array count]-1];
        [string appendString:obj];

    }];

    return array;
}
```

Now use it like

```
NSString *letters = @"ABCDEFकट्रತ್ಯÖäüℝijgrvਉਤਸੁਕsasas";
NSArray *arraysWith9Letters = [letters arraysBySplittingWithMaximumSize:9 options:NSStringEnumerationByComposedCharacterSequences] ;
NSLog(@"%@", arraysWith9Letters);

NSString *lorem = @"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam";
NSArray *loremArray = [lorem arraysBySplittingWithMaximumSize:9 options:NSStringEnumerationByWords];
NSLog(@"%@", loremArray);
```

Comment: Thank you for your opinion and your implementation, I will consider accepting after a day, just maybe another answer might occur :). That's a great code you'v written here but for wider usage. But is it worth it to implement it, if i know that i will never get different strings only E|V|R + 8numbers?

Comment: a category makes it dead simple to re-use code. when it is so simple to write code, that can be used in different situation, why not?

Comment: @vikingosegundo: your method is just awesome. OP's two method cant compete with your block based. I have a doubt between 1 and 2 w.r.t. memory and complexity. How can we find the complexity of both the methods?

Comment: @AnoopVaidya — are you talking of BigO?

Comment: @vikingosegundo : Yes

Comment: @AnoopVaidya — all solutions are linear, actually mine is O(2n), but in BigO constant values dont count, so it is O(n)

Comment: And what about memory usage...as Ist one is calling a lot memory, that will push the stack...

Comment: I didnt test it. feel free to do so and report back.

Comment: Tested and works elegantly +1